# Adding Sharepoint List Item to Windows form list

Tags: sharepoint, splistitem

How Can I add SharePoint SPList items in Windows form list based on index for SharePoint list instead of field name?

Comment: Could you explain you problem  in detail?

Comment: I am iterating through Sharepoint List and I want to add second field in the ListItem into a windows form list. I dont want to refer ny field by name instead I want to refer by index.

Comment: You want to refer to the field by index or you want to refer to the list item by index?

Comment: I want to refer the field by index

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, made fresh while drinking morning coffee. Good luck!

```
var list = siteWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
if (list == null)
{
    return;
}

var items = list.GetItems(query);

var countOfItems = items.Count;

if (countOfItems == 0)
{
    return;
}

var listItemFieldObjects = items.Cast<SPListItem>().Select(item => item[1]);

foreach (var item in listItemFieldObjects)
{
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem("Object's value");
    listView.BeginUpdate();
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(item.ToString());
    listView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    listView.EndUpdate();
}
```